# is it possible in vb.net to declare a variable as a string if it has already been declared as a date?

Tags: vb.net

I am declaring this variable in my vb.net application:

```
Dim invoice_due_date As Date = get_invoice_due_date(InvoiceDate.Text, customer_sequence)
```

i want to have an if statement that will declare this variable again as a `String` rather than a `Date`

is this possible?

i tried putting the `If` below but it tells me it hides a variable in an enclosing block

Comment: Why do you need a seperate string var?  `invoice_due_date.ToString()` will serve the same purpose

Comment: No.  As you have already discovered, you cannot declare two variables with the exact same name within the same scope.  Since you are unclear, though, regarding *why* you would need to do this, we can't help you with any alternatives.

Comment: The reason for this, is because I want to set the date by default then based on a condition, if it's true then I need to set the string to "N/A" instead of a date

Comment: But what are you going to do with this string/date after that. You could declare it as an object but it doesn't do you any good if whatever you are passing it too cannot handle it.

Comment: It's going to be used in word as a bookmark value and also inserted into a database

Comment: `If myBool Then Print "N/A" Else Print myDt.ToString(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up (google) on "variable scope". What you want is not only not possible, it would be bad practice.

You either declare a new variable (different name) with a different data type and load the contents of `invoice_due_date` into it or, as @Plutonix already suggested, use `.ToString()`